# AnkhSVN Error in Visual Studio 2022 17.2.5

Tags: ankhsvn

After upadting Visual Studio to Latest Version AnkhSVN show this error on loading solutions:

```
System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.CommonIDE.Solutions.SolutionPropertyBag' to type 'Ankh.Scc.Native.ICOMPropertyBag'.
   at Ankh.VSPackage.AnkhSvnPackage.ReadSolutionProps(IVsHierarchy pHierarchy, String pszProjectName, String pszProjectMk, String pszKey, Int32 fPreLoad, IPropertyBag pPropBag)
```

Any Help will be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue has been solved in new versions of this extension.
The developper of this Visual Studio's extension do not publish it's developments on Visual Studio market but on Gihub.
here is the address on it`s Github project:
https://github.com/AmpScm/AnkhSVN
[This one comment on top](https://github.com/AmpScm/AnkhSVN/issues/44#issuecomment-1116680677) is help for how to download the installable file for persons new to Github like me

Comment: This solution has solved the problem. Do not forget to sign in to GitHub. Otherwise, the builds are not downloadable.

Answer (score 2):

In the solution file, try to delete the below GlobalSection defining the dependency to Ankhsvn:

```
GlobalSection(SubversionScc) = preSolution
    Svn-Managed = True
    Manager = AnkhSVN - Subversion Support for Visual Studio
EndGlobalSection
```

This worked in my older solutions, created in previous versions of Visual Studio.

Comment: I have change the solution following your guidance, and another error happened

`The source control provider associated with this solution could not be found. The projects will be treated as not under source control.
Do you want to permanently remove the source bindings from the projects? Yes/No`
I have said yes and .csproj file changed to:
<SccProjectName></SccProjectName>
<SccLocalPath></SccLocalPath>
<SccAuxPath></SccAuxPath>
<SccProvider></SccProvider>
And finally, there is no error on reloading the solution.
But is the solution still on source control?

Comment: @Hamedb Hi, it seems like your solution is not under source control, anymore.   you shouldn't see any Ankh svn icons too.

Comment: When the latest AnkhSVN version is installed/updated in the VS2022 extensions (as mentioned by @EhsanAbidi in above answer) No Scc* tags are needed in the VS solution file to keep the solution under SVN source control.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I ignored the error then added the solution to SVN. Upon closing the project it asked to save it, but say NO (otherwise I would get a save error). After that I was able to use the reopen and use the project without issue, including building/opening/closing the project and checking into SVN with no errors.